# Child Process / Parent Process

Tags: c, unix, terminal, child-process

I am studying child process and parent process in Unix system.

My questions are below.

1. I am not sure about those two concepts. Could you please give me some detail about those two concepts?
2. I am running a program in terminal and want to know how to tell which one is child process and parent process.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading an article/documentation on child processes on Unix? This is quite a broad question

Comment: Where can I see it? and I am not sure how to tell which one is child process among the screen shot.

Comment: Try googling `Unix Processes` or `Unix child processes` or `Unix parent processes`, there's many pages of information you can look up

Comment: technically all processes are child processes except for init which is the first process to run and the one that spawns everything else

Comment: Look at the headings of the columns.  The one that says PID is the process ID.  The one that says PPID is the parent process of PID.

Comment: Type `man tool-you-used-to-provide-the-list-you-show` and read the tools documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one kind of process in Unix. Each one has a unique id called the *pid*. With the exception of number 1, all processes are *spawned* by another process. The spawning is done by a system call called `fork()`. With respect to a fork, the process that does the forking is called the parent process and the process that is forked is called the child process. Every process except process id 1 is a child of some other process. So the answer to

> which one is child process

is all of them except the one with pid 1

In the `ps` listing you showed there will be a column called `PID` This column contains the pid of the process described in that line. There will also be a column called `PPID` and that shows the id of the parent process i.e. the one that forked it.